# Change the sleep icon in login window (loginwindow.app)

Tags: macos, applications, icon, login, login-screen

I would like to change the sleep icon in the login window. I've found loginwindow.app (/System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app) and replaced Sleep.tiff with the desired image with identical file dpi and size wise (yes that is the superhot logo).[image] I then ran `sudo killall loginwindow`, thinking that I would relaunch the app and it would use the new icon. Instead, it logged me out and didn't use the new icon. Is there any way to replace this icon? [image] ^when it logged me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this can be changed in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LoginUIKit.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/LoginUICore.framework/Resources/`, I’ll post if it works when I change it there

I got the correct location from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/350732/how-to-change-login-pic-for-other)